# testcafe - Source files do not contain valid 'fixture' and 'test' declarations

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm writing a test in testcafe for the first time, and trying to do a `forEach` loop in order to iterate various files.
When trying to run the test, getting this error `Source files do not contain valid 'fixture' and 'test' declarations.`

```
import testcafe from 'testcafe';
import { promises } from 'fs';
import { parse } from 'node-html-parser';

let specFiles: string[] = [];

fixture ('OpsLevel test cafe reporter').before( async t => {
    specFiles = await promises.readdir('./gauge-reports/html-report/specs')    
});

specFiles.forEach(specFile => {
    test(`Generate testcafe report from ${specFile}`, async t => {
        const gaugeReport = await promises.readFile(specFile, {encoding: 'utf8', flag: 'r'});
        const parsedReport = parse(gaugeReport);
        const structuredText = parsedReport.structuredText;
    
        await t.expect(structuredText.includes('Success Rate 100%')).eql(true);
    });
});
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Runtime DataSet initialization for data driven tests is not supported. Please refer to the [documentation](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402804/recipes/best-practices/create-data-driven-tests#header) to learn how to properly initialize a dataset.